# How to embed a node's NID in the title of a node?

Tags: 8, hooks, nodes

I know the [Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module exists, but it is only for Drupal 7.

Is there a method of automatically assigning the title with the NID upon clicking submit? I know that the NID doesn't exist until the submit button is hit. How would one embed the NID in the title?

What hook would one use?

Comment: Have you tried Auto EntityLabel for D8? A dev branch exists. Have you also tried Rules?

Comment: @Kevin unfortunately, Rules 8 is MIA.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do two step:

**Step one:** auto generate the title and hidden form. use hook_field_widget_form_alter() with code

```
function MY_MODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  $bundle = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->bundle();
  // You can check with other bundle
  if ($field_definition->getName() == 'title' && $bundle == 'page' && $element['value']['#default_value'] == '') {
    $element['#required'] = FALSE;
    //hidden title  
    $element['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $element['value']['#required'] = FALSE;
    // Set default value
    $element['value']['#default_value'] = 'Default Title';
  }
}
```

with step one you can cross submit form.

**Step two:** Override new title with default value. Use hook_node_insert()

```
function MY_MODULE_node_insert(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'page') {
    $new_title = 'New title ' . $node->id();
    $node->setTitle($new_title);
    $node->setNewRevision(FALSE);
    $node->save();  
  }
}
```

Comment: If it has the the nid, which is the only information only available after saving, then this is the right way. Anything else, like the date or something like that would be possible from presave hook, which would be faster as you wouldn't have to resave twice. If you really need this, you should also add a check to make sure that title is not the default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Hook Post Action](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action) module

> So this module introduces several new Drupal hooks to overcome this
>   limitation
>
> - hook_entity_postsave
> - hook_entity_postinsert
> - hook_entity_postupdate
> - hook_entity_postdelete
> - hook_node_postsave
> - hook_node_postinsert
> - hook_node_postupdate
> - hook_node_postdelete

and one you have it installed you can use the `hook_node_postsave()` hook

In the [Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module page says:

> Be advised that there is a better maintained alternative available:
>   https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old issue, but here's my take. 
Let's say you need this for node add article.

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function MYMODULE_form_node_article_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    // Hide title field to avoid confusion
    $form['title']['#access'] = FALSE;
    // Set a temporary title because it's always required on node save.
    $form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'Dummy title';

}

function MYMODULE_node_insert(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'article') {
    $new_title = 'Title ' . $node->id();
    $node->setTitle($new_title);
    $node->setNewRevision(FALSE);
    $node->save();
  }
}
```